# How to display values from arrays located inside separate JSON files depending on the day the site is visited

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, date

The code below *should* load values from different JSON files into the `arr` array, depending on which date the site is visited.

**Expected behavior:**

If you visit/refresh the site on 2020-04-15, you should get a random value picked from `file-1.json`.

If you visit/refresh the site on 2020-04-16, you should get a random value picked from `file-2.json`.

...

Ad infinitum.

Here is my `scripts.js` file:

```
//Populate calendar with dates
var getDaysArray = function(start, end) {
    for(var arr=[],dt=new Date(start); dt<=end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)){
        arr.push(new Date(dt));
    }
    return arr;
};
var calendar = getDaysArray(new Date("2020-04-15"),new Date("2021-01-01"));
calendar.map((v)=>v.toISOString().slice(0,10)).join("")
console.log(calendar);


var arr = [];

function isToday(dateParameter) {
        var today = new Date();
        return dateParameter.getDate() === today.getDate() && dateParameter.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && dateParameter.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear();

}

Promise.all(
calendar.filter(d=>isToday(new Date(d))).map((today,i)=>{
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    //Get the json based on index
    $.getJSON(`file-${i+1}.json`, resolve);
  })
}))
.then(smcs=>{
  //Iterate through array of the data.. Should be two dimensional array with one array in it
  for(const array of smcs){
    // You can use $.each here but this is simpler
    arr = [...arr,...array]
  }
})
.then(()=>{
  //Random pick
  console.log(arr);
  $("#show").text(arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]);
})
```

My `file-1.json`:

```
[
"Green", 
"Aqua", 
"Blue"
]
```

My `file-2.json`:

```
[
"Violet", 
"Orange", 
"Pink"
]
```

And here is a demo I published on Netlify, for your convenience: https://bluwind.netlify.com

**Questions:**

1. How can I make this have the expected behavior and "associate" each json file with a each day?
2. How can I test it to see how it will work if someone visited the site tomorrow?
3. Is there a better way of accomplishing this task? I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks a lot for reading through this and I welcome any feedback. Please help me before I lose my mind with this code.

Cheers :)

Comment: Why isn't the data file included as a resource by the server, then the script just reads whichever dataset its been given.

Comment: What do you mean by data file? The json files? @RobG

Comment: `$.getJSON(`file-${i+1}.json`, resolve);` That (I guess).

Comment: Any idea how to accomplish that? Not sure what's wrong with that line exactly.

Comment: You can take the difference in days from the current date and subtract with the first date you want the first json to be loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the difference in days from today's date as the offset value for your json file. Something like

```
// Store today's date
const today = new Date();
// Define milliseconds per day
const msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24;
// Get difference (in days) between two dates
function getDiffInDays(date1, date2){
    // `|0` is same as Math.floor(...)
    return ((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/msPerDay)|0;
}
// Get date by offset in days (Useful for testing tomorrow's date and so on)
function getDateByOffset(days=0){
    const today = new Date();
    return new Date((today.getTime()/msPerDay + days)*msPerDay);
}
// Get offset index for the json file
function getIndex(){
    // Define the starting date for "file-1.json"
    const startDate = new Date(Date.parse('4/15/2020'));
    // Will range from 1 instead of 0
    return getDiffInDays(startDate, today) + 1;
}
new Promise(resolve=>{
    // Get the json file based on the offset
    $.getJSON(`file-${getIndex()}.json`, resolve);
})
.then(json=>{
    // Add it to the `arr` array
    arr = [...arr,...json];
})
.then(()=>{
    console.log(arr);
    $("#show").text(arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your work! I've changed `data-${getIndex()}.json` to `file-$...` and added `var arr = [];` but what do I need to do to test how it would look tomorrow for instance? @xxMrPHDxx

Comment: Use the function `getDateByOffset` I created. Replace `const today = new Date();` with `const today = getDateByOffset(1);` for tomorrow @Fraktar

Comment: Got this in console: `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration today before initialization script.js:14:5` @xxMrPHDxx

Comment: I've update the function `getDateByOffset` cause it's using the `today` variable before it was initialized @Fraktar

Comment: @Fraktar Also, make sure you initialized `msPerDay` before `today`

Comment: Got the array from the second file `file-2.json` when I replace `const today = new Date();` with `const today = getDateByOffset(1);` I believe that's the expected behavior, right? @xxMrPHDxx

Comment: @Fraktar Yes, I think so. You can try to access it tomorrow then. Also, you most likely don't need the `calendar` array and the `getDaysArray` thingy

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Will accept your answer tomorrow @xxMrPHDxx

Comment: Yes, already removed both the `calendar` and the `getDaysArray`. Your code made those redundant I believe @xxMrPHDxx

Comment: It seems that people in different timezones are getting different results. The UTC time is not universal, how can I change that? @xxMrPHDxx

Comment: If you set the local computer clock ahead you get values from tomorrow's array, which is not the expected behavior. Is it possible to fix that? @xxMrPHDxx

Comment: You can get the date through the user's public ip from [World Time API](http://worldtimeapi.org) @Fraktar

Comment: Not sure how to use that, but thanks! Posted a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286220/using-js-server-time-instead-of-client-time-to-avoid-this-behavior-where-users-c @xxMrPHDxx