# Using JS server time instead of client time to avoid this behavior where users can manipulate results by changing their local machine clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, time

**Expected behavior**

Show users a random value (color) from the `arr` array on each refresh. Each day a different file (`file-1.json`, `file-2.json`, etc) should be loaded into `arr`. This should reset at 00:00 UTC server time. Only values from that day's associated file should be displayed.

**Unexpected behavior**

All works well, until users change the clock on their local machines/phones. Then they can effectively see future & past values as well. Date/time can be manipulated client-side, which shouldn't happen. Everyone should get the server's time, whatever that is.

**Examples**

- **Good**: if you visit/refresh the site on 2020-04-18, you should get a random color picked from `file-1.json`.
- **Good**: if you visit/refresh the site on 2020-04-19, you should get a random color picked from `file-2.json`.
- **Bad**: on the other hand, if on 2020-04-18 you change your local clock to 2020-04-19, you **shouldn't** be able to get a random color from 2020-04-19 since that date is in the future. You should still get a value from today's file, since it is still 2020-04-18 server time.

`script.js`:

```
// Store today's date
const today = new Date();
var arr = [];
// Define milliseconds per day
const msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24;

// Uncomment line below to test future date by using the getDateByOffset() function
//const today = getDateByOffset(1);

// Get difference (in days) between two dates
function getDiffInDays(date1, date2){
    // `|0` is same as Math.floor(...)
    return ((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/msPerDay)|0;
}
// Get date by offset in days (Useful for testing tomorrow's date and so on)
function getDateByOffset(days=0){
    const today = new Date();
    return new Date((today.getTime()/msPerDay + days)*msPerDay);
}

// Get offset index for the json file
function getIndex(){
    // Define the starting date for "file-1.json"
    const startDate = new Date(Date.parse('4/18/2020'));
    // Will range from 1 instead of 0
    return getDiffInDays(startDate, today) + 1;
}
new Promise(resolve=>{
    // Get the json file based on the offset
    $.getJSON(`file-${getIndex()}.json`, resolve);
})
.then(json=>{
    // Add it to the `arr` array
    arr = [...arr,...json];
})
.then(()=>{
    console.log(arr);
    $("#show").text(arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]);
})
```

**[DEMO on Netlify](https://bluwind.netlify.app)**

**How to replicate the issue**

Simply change your local machine or phone's clock to 2020-04-19. Then you would get tomorrow's colors.

**EDIT: just to be 100% clear, whatever the user does with his local device settings (change clock, IP address, etc) -- he should NOT be able to influence the website time.**

**EDIT2: created this endpoint to retrieve date and time: https://bluexpress.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/server/getdate but I'm not sure if it's the right solution or how to properly integrate it into the site. Assistance appreciated!**

Comment: You can only do this based on the server clock (and hence timezone setting) as the client can change not only their system settings but also their IP address to pretend to be anywhere they want at (almost) any time they want.

Comment: Makes sense. Any idea how to accomplish that? If you could at least point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it @RobG

Answer (score 1):

Then answer is simple: don't compute the file name on the client, rather make it a single URI which dynamically computes the JSON on the server depending on the day.

As long as the client can request any of the JSON data by changing the URI, users which are a little bit savvy can access past and future days, even without changing the clock. As a general rule, don't trust the client, always make sure to check things on the server.

That being said, you could also keep the client logic but make the server deny (e.g. 404 or so) access to the file of the "wrong day" depending on the date. But you'll have to have server logic to rule out client-side abuse.

Comment: Thanks for your input! "Simple" is relative though, no idea how to accomplish any of that. @Lucero

Comment: @Fraktar you need to write server side coding, like node.js, php, ruby, jsp, java, python etc

Answer (score 1):

the answer can be given based on

1. If the HTML is rendered using a server side script
2. If you have a sever endpoint to retrieve the date and time of the server

you can do either one of it and get the server's time to javascript's visible scope as a variable

Then use that variable to decide the file names as `file-1` `file-2` etc

To use Node.JS server side code, please follow [Netlify: Punch Setup](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/03/04/a-step-by-step-guide-punch-on-netlify/)

Comment: Thanks! I've been recommended [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) and [WorldTimeAPI](http://worldtimeapi.org/) but I'm not sure how to implement those solutions. @Dickens A S

Comment: do ajax to `http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe` change `Europe` to your country, you will get time of that country

Comment: @Fraktar—you really don't need a date library to get the current time on a client. And it will not help with geolocation at all.

Comment: I though the requirement is not to use the user's laptop's time, where the user has intentions to change it, may it is a negative case

Comment: @DickensAS yes, that is exact. It should NOT matter what the user does: change his device time/date or IP. If the server time is set to X then the user should not be allowed to change it to Y, whatever he does with his local device settings.

Comment: @DickensAS thanks for the Netlify link, will look into that right now, although I don't have any NodeJS experience, hopefully it isn't going to take me an eternity to make this happen.

Comment: It seems like Punch is no longer maintained @DickensAS

Comment: You can use expressjs - https://expressjs.com/ which is probably the most used in enterprise

Comment: Alright, what should I attempt to create with expressjs? @DickensAS

Comment: in express you can have plain html simply placed in a folder which will render as it is, then second step you create a rest url using express code very easy only 4 lines, in that 4 lines you get the date and use the `send`, then call it via AJAX you will get the server date

Answer (score 1):

You can use [World Time API](http://worldtimeapi.org)'s `/api/ip` feature to get the api based on the user's public ip address. Something like

```
// Modify the getIndex function to receive today's date instead
function getIndex(today){
    const startDate = new Date(Date.parse('4/15/2020'));
    const offset = getDiffInDays(startDate, today) + 1;
    return offset;
}   
// Get date from server
function getServerDate(){
    // Unfortunately, we need to bypass Cross-Origin Request (CORs)
    return fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip`)
    // Convert response to json
    .then(res=>res.json())
    // Get the datetime from object and create a Date object
    .then(({datetime})=>new Date(Date.parse(datetime)))
    // Get json index based on the date
    .then(getIndex);
}
```

And using above function you can simply

```
// Get today's date from server
getServerDate()
.then(index=>new Promise(resolve=>{
    // Get the json file based on the index returned
    $.getJSON(`data-${index}.json`, resolve);
}))
.then(json=>{
    // Append to arr and whatever you like here
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I get this error: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` @xxMrPHDxx

Comment: My bad. It's actually `worldtimeapi.org` @Fraktar

Comment: IP addresses are very unreliable for geolocation, even if the user isn't using a VPN.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But since it's using the proxified Heroku app with CORS, it only uses the heroku app's host ip @RobG

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx I've created this endpoint to retrieve date and time: https://bluexpress.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/server/getdate using Netlify (https://github.com/neverendingqs/netlify-express). Is that better than the worldtimeapi?

Comment: @Fraktar Just replace the fetch url with `https://bluexpress.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/server/getdate` and instead of extracting `({datetime})`, you would want to extract `date` instead through `({date})`

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx How does that prevent users from actually getting the files with another than today's index?

Comment: The user can't possibly change the server's date @Lucero

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx No, but they can just request another JSON file from the server nevertheless. If users are malicious enough to change their computer clock, they can also just pop open dev tools and change the URL when it is being requested.

Comment: They shouldn't be able to because the api that he created doesn't have a way to pass like an offset. It will just return the current date based on the server's local time. Also, if you afraid some users will try to change the `startDate` to bypass the system, he can just do the offset thingy in the api itself. @Lucero